# How to create dynamic D3 tickFormat in dc charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, chart.js, bar-chart

I am looking to get rid of decimal numbers from the axis of my chart, and achieve what I need using d3 formatting of `d3.format(",d")` while if the data in the chart loads with numbers over 999 I need a different format ie `d3.format(",.2s")` (so large numbers will have SI units 1000000 => 1M), something that functions like this would be nice:

```
_chart.yAxis().ticks(5).tickFormat(
    isDecimalInAxis ? localD3.numberFormat(",d") : localD3.numberFormat(".2s") ? localD3.numberFormat(",d") : localD3.numberFormat(".2s") )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the datum is smaller than `999` and apply the desired format. For instance:

```
.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d < 999 ? d3.format(",d")(d) : d3.format(".2s")(d)
})
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 2000])
  .range([10, 580]);
d3.axisBottom(scale).tickFormat(function(d) {
  return d < 999 ? d3.format(",d")(d) : d3.format(".2s")(d)
})(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,50)"))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600"></svg>
```